# Return random numbers from lists of varying size with weights

Tags: python, random, train-test-split

I would like to split existing data for a train-test-split in python. Functions like `sklearn.train_test_split()` typically choose evenly distributed values as testdata. But since I want to check, whether my model can deal with skewed data (more training data on "the left side of the function") I need to weigh the split more towards the left side of my data.

I thought about using `random.choices()` and specifying the weights here, but that seems odd since the list containing the weights would have to be very long.

I´m basically looking for a function that I can pass my list and tell it to choose n random numbers from this list, but weigh the first ~30% of entries significantly higher than the rest.

Does anyone have an idea?

Edit: Here is some basic code demonstrating the problem:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# Apply function I´m looking for
l_train, l_test = function(l, testsize=0.5)
# Apply sklearn train/test/split
l_train_sk, l_test_sk = sklearn.train_test_split(l, testsize=0.5)


# Output:
l_train = [1, 3, 7, 2, 4]
l_test = [6, 9, 10, 5, 8]

l_train_sk = [2, 4, 8, 9, 3]
l_test_sk = [1, 6, 10, 5, 7]
```

As can be seen the split has been applied so that 50% of the data can be used as training data. Also the sklearn function randomly selects data from the left (1,2,3,4,5) and the right (6,7,8,9,10) side of the data whereas the function I´m looking for overweighs data from the left side significantly in the training dataset.

Does this make clear what the objective is?

Comment: Can you share the code you have worked on so far?

Comment: I can share an example, yes. I´ll add it to the question.

Comment: Can you explain what "weight" means in your question

Comment: Sorry I cannot really understand your question fully

Comment: Yes, so with weight I´m trying to express, that more datapoints from one side of the list should be used as training points. Think of it this way: I have a distribution of points, that seem to follow a sine curve. If I fit my model with evenly distributed points it will easly find the sine curve as the correct solution. What I want to test is what happens, if I use a lot of points from the left side of the distribution (where the sine curve would start from zero and rise, then fall again) as training data. Can the model still find the sine curve as the best fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

First I created a list of cummulative probabilities with the weights I want:

```
# Input Array X_temp: np.array((n,1))
len_half = int(len(X_temp) / 2)
focus_left = 70 # choose values from the left side with a probability of 70%

cum_gesamt = []
cum_left = [x * ((focus_left * 100) / len_half) for x in np.linspace(1, len_half, len_half)]
cum_right = [((focus_left * 100) + (x * (((1 - focus_left) * 100) / len_half))) for x in np.linspace(1, len_half, len_half)]
cum_gesamt.extend(cum_left)
cum_gesamt.extend(cum_right)
```

Then I could then randomly choose entries of indices:

```
double = 1
while len(double) != 0:
    count += 1
    train_index = random.choices( np.linspace(0, len(X_temp) - 1, len(X_temp)),cum_weights=cum_gesamt, k=int((1 - test_size) * len(X_temp)),)
    double = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(train_index).items() if count > 1]
```

The list `train_index` now contains randomly selected index entries that I could now use to get my elements from the list:

```
Xtrain_temp = np.array([(X_temp[int(x)]) for x in train_index])
```

So this is a workaround that isn´t great but it works for me. Maybe someone else can benefit of these ideas.